# How to use goal seek function in Excel user function?

Tags: excel, vba, seek, excel-udf

There is method to use goal seek in MS excel like follows code. It works fine.

```
   Sub GSeek() 
      With Worksheets("Sheet1") 
             .Range("H18").GoalSeek _  
              Goal:=.Range("H21").Value, _ 
               ChangingCell:=.Range("G18")
     End With 
   End Sub
```

And I would like to use a function to do the goal seek like follows.

```
  Function fSeek(a As Range, b As Range, c As Range)
     a.GoalSeek Goal:=b.Value, ChangingCell:=c
     fSeek = "Ok"
   End Function
```

However, the code work peacefully and no answer was got in the range c. Where am I wrong?

Comment: User-Defined Functions (UDF) are not allowed to change other cells when invoked from a formula.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Are there any way to get the same goal? I really want to seek many goals in the same worksheet.

Comment: You can do that, but via macros not via formulas.

Comment: But macros can not use parameters. Sub procedures with parameters are not show the macro list at all.

Comment: You can always find a way to specify what you want to seek and with what parameters. If those are not a-priori known cells, you can use forms or `InputBox` (inside the macro) to let the user enter them.

Comment: I really appreciate your advice. I can now do the goal seek with a macro by using inputBox to select the cells as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I am writing an answer because it seems this question is resurging.

Bottom line is that **User-Defined Functions (UDF) are not allowed to change other cells when invoked from a formula**.

Solution: **To automate godl-seeking, write a VBA macro, not a UDF**.

A macro can automate goal-seeking on any range or set of cells. Since a macro does not have parameters, there are many ways to permit the user specify the set of cells to `GoalSeek` and the parameters, and to route these to the `Range.GoalSeek` method:

1- Design a dedicated `UserForm`

2- Use VBA's `InputBox` function, or possibly Excel's `Application.InputBox` fuction with parameter `type:=8` to enter a range.

3- dedicate some cells on the worksheet where the user can enter the parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have succeeded to create a dialog to do goal seeking as your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for answering me. I found my question again here after a long time. 
I happened to find the solution to the this question by using the event.

In the Microsoft Excel Object-Sheet1(Sheet1), we can only write the following code:

```
 '----------------------------------------------
 ' Goal seeking when the worksheet changes.
 '----------------------------------------------
 ' Here we want to do goal seek for Range("H18") 
 '  with the Goal cell as  Range("H21") 
 '  and  the changing cell as Range("G18").
 '
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     Range("H18").GoalSeek Goal:=Range("H21"), ChangingCell:=Range("G18")
 End Sub
```

Is it cool?

Yun