# VBA goalseek trouble

Tags: excel, vba

Using goalseek in VBA to find the grade I need on my final exam to get an A. Currently using:

```
Function AFinalGrade(SetExamLocation As Range, SetGradeLocation As Range)
    ExamLocation = SetExamLocation.Address
    GradeLocation = SetGradeLocation.Address
    AFinalGrade = Range(GradeLocation).GoalSeek Goal:=.9, ChangingCell=:Range(ExamLocation))
End Function
```

Whenever I try to run this I get a syntax error statement. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `GoalSeek` is not a function that returns a value... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45046979/how-to-use-goal-seek-function-in-excel-user-function/46968528#46968528

Answer (score 0):

```
Range(Cells(14, (i * 3) + 22).Address).GoalSeek Goal:=A, ChangingCell:=Range(Cells(8, (i * 3) + 21).Address)
```